# Eclipse - Android project name

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm generating Android projects based on database contains all required data to make a new project.
My Android project generate successfully, but when I import this project folder to my eclipse to generate "Signed APK" file, eclipse names all projects with same name (same name with launcher activity).
Is there any way to force eclipse to name every project with different project name than other projects?

Comment: You need to show us how you're generating projects and importing them to Eclipse.

Comment: I ment, which file or tag tells Eclipse my project name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse names every imported project as a launcher activity's name. But you can manually rename your project in Eclipse, using context_menu->Refactor->Rename.